# Xcode 9.4.1 and Foundation Framework

Tags: xcode, foundation

Hello I'm new to programming in Objective-C. I'm reading the book "Programing in Objective-C Developers Library" and they're asking me to create a command line project using the foundation framework, but when I go to create one, I don't see an option to use Foundation.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first screen shot shows it:

[image]

You've already selected Command Line Tool, which is correct. So now click Next and you will be creating a command line tool that uses the Foundation framework. In your second screen shot, enter a name for the tool and click Next; you will then be asked for a place to Save this project. Do so. When you do, the code for *main.m* will say:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See that first line? That is "using the Foundation framework".

Comment: O ok it just looks different than the pics that the book is showing me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing to know is that Foundation is so important in Objective-C that it's practically part of the language. It provides classes like `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and many others that we assume are always available. So Foundation is special in that every Objective-C project will use it, and it'll be included in any project templates like the Command Line Tool template you're working from. Other project templates will include additional frameworks (e.g. the Cocoa App template will set up your project with AppKit for you), and if you want to use other frameworks you'll add them yourself after you create the project.